# How can I save the formulas of my excel sheet and later restore then?

Tags: excel

I have an excel app that modifies/delete/recreate several sheets, so formulas in other sheets that references any of those deleted sheets lose the references. What I need is to save the formulas before deleting/recreating the sheets and later restore all of then.
I wrote a couple of classes to accomplish this, one of then save the formulas as cell comments, the other one save them to a dictionary but the retoration process is very slow on both and I need to do it very fast. Thanks to all the comunity of Stackoverflow.

Pedro.

Answer (score 0):

I just replace "=" with a unique text string like "xyxyxy" on all the sheets with formulae.

Then delete and replace as needed.

Then do the replace of xyxyxy with = on all sheets and the formulae work again as normal.